# Error connecting Qliksense Cloud to redshift

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to connect Qliksense Cloud to Amazon Redshift and get a timeout error establishing a connection and it asks whether my server is accepting TCP connections on port 5439. As far as I know, it is set up properly. I even opened port 5439 explicitly on security groups of the VPC but getting the same error. There doesn't seem to be any good and latest documentation or videos out there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out these resources:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQQWeve3xIs
- http://cdn.qlik.com/media/QlikView%20Integration%20with%20Amazon%20Redshift.pdf

Also, first try "allow-all in-out" in the Firewall. if then it is working then it's a FW issue. If it's not working then it's a config issue.

Check in Amazon if you whitelisted your QS server IP address.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have checked this out. The video and document apply to the desktop version. I'm looking to use same in the cloud version - Qlik Sense Cloud. It seems straightforward but it isn't. On AWS, I've allowed any traffic to coma and go on the vpc where redshift cluster is.